# make a button alert its testID, in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want this Button to alert its testID, when I press it:

here is my code:

```
<Button
   testID = "buttttt"
   ref    = {(Button) => {b = Button;}}
   title  = "Learn More"
   color  = "#841584"
   accessibilityLabel = "Learn more about this purple button"
   onPress = {() => alert(testID)}
 />
```

Its giving me **undefined**.

I think the solution has to do with ref.

Thanks.

Comment: give more information about the error or show the whole error data. Do you want to check the working of the Button or Alert, here?

Comment: it's just alerting: undefined.   I tried different approaches, down in the answers you can find.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be doing `this.b.props.testId` instead of `this.testId` in your onPress handler. Something like this:

```
    <Button
      testID="buttttt"
      ref={(b)=>{this.b = b;}}
      title="Learn More"
      color="#841584"
      accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      onPress={()=>alert(this.b.props.testID)}
    />
```

Comment: @BashirAbdelwahed tried with `this.b.props.testID` and it worked for me.

Comment: What's the `alert` function? Try `onPress={() => { Alert.alert("Title", this.b.props.testID)}}/>` - You can see an example using the answer by @DhruvParmar working. https://snack.expo.io/BkxmoNQPZ

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this.getAttribute("testID")`.

And you should use `data-testid` as attribute name. That's better style and you can access it via `this.dataset.testid` too.

Comment: I wrote : onPress={()=>alert(this.getAttribute("testID"))}  . it gave me an error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.getAttribute("testID")')

Comment: Use vanilla JavaScript: `onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('testID'))"`. That should work.

Comment: it didn't work. I think because the onPress props is defined in the react-native button JSX. so it's not plain javaScript. so nothing happened because the onPress prop is the one responsible for handeling the click.